# MySQL Sorting Results takes a long time

Tags: mysql, performance

Lately I've been getting MySQL to hang on specific queries. I have a table with 500,000+ records. Here is the query being run:

> SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE (itemlist_id = 115626)  ORDER BY tableOrder DESC LIMIT 1

Here is the explain:

> |  1 | SIMPLE      | items | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 587113 | Using where; Using filesort |

And here is the process_list entry:

> | 252996 | root | localhost | itemdb | Query   |    0 | Sorting result | SELECT * FROM `items`     WHERE (itemlist_id = 115642)  ORDER BY tableOrder DESC LIMIT 1 |

Any idea what could be causing this query to take 10 minutes to process? When I run it manually it's done quickly. (1 row in set (0.86 sec))

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's the sorting that's slow, and not finding the record?  If you've got a table scan of 500k+ records on a field that's not indexed it could take a while.   And the "manual" quickness could be because MySQL (or the OS) has cached in the data from an earlier attempt and runs that much faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create an index on `items (itemList_id, TableOrder)` and rewrite the query a little:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    items
WHERE   itemlist_id = 115626
ORDER BY
        itemlist_id DESC, tableOrder DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The first condition in `ORDER BY` may seem to be redundant, but it helps `MySQL` to choose the correct plan (which does not sort).

Comment: Thanks! I added the index and the query, and now it's blazing fast.

Comment: may you please give a resource for the edit you made to the query. it is very important to understand why for me.

Comment: @TDSii: I made the edit based on the `MySQL` docs and my experience.